# ASP.net website deployed in IIS not ever loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net website, which is fully working is visual studio. no errors what so ever.
Then I started iis and added a new website. I have set the path to the website but the website is never stopping with loading. I have no clue what the problem is... In an earlier version there where no problems....

Whatever i do now. rolling back to the old website or the current the webpages is loading into infinity.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I have no experience with IIS. I installed it and the i created a new website. i had to set the physical path to it. and the it worked... This was the first time...

I made some changed to the solution and the i Replaced the files... this time the website is loading into infinity

Comment: You'll need to provide much more detail. Like the IIS configuration, how you deployed, etc. Nobody can answer your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

How do you publish the app? Via visual studio?
It could be a number of things. Usually the problem is access, rights, missing libs/files, firewall, port, url, redirects or maybe IIS app config - when creating a new app I sometimes forget to fix the application pool to .net 4 in IIS.